# Function- and Type substitutions or Views in Coq

Tags: list, heap, coq, isomorphism

I proved some theorems about lists, and extracted algorithms from them. Now I want to use heaps instead, because lookup and concatenation are faster. What I currently do to achieve this is to just use custom definitions for the extracted list type. I would like to do this in a more formal way, but ideally without having to redo all of my proofs. Lets say I have a type

```
Heap : Set -> Set
```

and an isomorphism

```
f : forall A, Heap A -> List A.
```

Furthermore, I have functions H_app and H_nth, such that

```
H_app (f a) (f b) = f (a ++ b)
```

and

```
H_nth (f a) = nth a
```

On the one hand, I would have to replace every list-recursion by a specialized function that mimics list recursion. On the other hand, beforehand I would want to replace `++` and `nth` by `H_app` and `H_nth`, so the extracted algorithms would be faster. The problem is that I use tactics like `simpl` and `compute` in some places, which will probably fail if I just replace everything in the proof code. It would be good to have a possibility to "overload" the functions afterwards.

Is something like this possible?

Edit: To clarify, a similar problem arises with numbers: I have some old proofs that use `nat`, but the numbers are getting too large. Using `BinNat` would be better, but is it possible to use `BinNat` instead of `nat` also in the old proofs without too much modification? (And especially, replace inefficient usages of `+` by the more efficient definition for `BinNat`?)

Comment: Could you add an example with a theorem that you proved about lists and wanted to use with heaps? Also, could you give the definition of heap?

Comment: The objective of my question is whether there is a way to be more flexible with the actual structure I use. Currently it is just an ordinary balanced tree, but I do not see how this is relevant.

Comment: Hm. A similar problem arises with numbers: I have some old proofs that use `nat`, but the numbers are getting too large. Using `BinNat` would be better, but is it possible to use `BinNat` instead of `nat` also in the old proofs without too much modification? (And especially, replace inefficient usages of `+` by the more efficient definition for `BinNat`?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for the sake of clarity, I take it that `Heap` must look like
this:

```
Inductive Heap A : Type :=
| Node : Heap A -> A -> Heap A -> Heap A
| Leaf : Heap A.
```

with `f` being defined as

```
Fixpoint f A (h : Heap A) : list A :=
  match h with
  | Node h1 a h2 => f h1 ++ a :: f h2
  | Leaf => []
  end.
```

If this is the case, then `f` does *not* define an isomorphism between
`Heap A` and `list A` for all `A`. Instead, we can find a function
`g : forall A, list A -> Heap A` such that

```
forall A (l : list A), f (g l) = l
```

Nevertheless, we would like to say that both `Heap` and `list` are
equivalent in some sense when they are used to implement the same
abstraction, namely sets of elements of some type.

There is a precise and formal way in which we can validate this idea
in languages that have [parametric polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism), such as Coq. This
principle, known as [parametricity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametricity), roughly says that
parametrically polymorphic functions respect relations that we impose
on types we instantiate them with.

This is a little bit abstract, so let's try to make it more
concrete. Suppose that you have a function over lists (say, `foo`)
that uses only `++` and `nth`. To be able to replace `foo` by an
equivalent version on `Heap` using parametricity, we need to make
`foo`'s definition polymorphic, abstracting over the functions over
lists:

```
Definition foo (T : Set -> Set)
               (app : forall A, T A -> T A -> T A)
               (nth : forall A, T A -> nat -> option A)
               A (l : T A) : T A :=
  (* ... *)
```

You would first prove properties of foo by instantiating it over
lists:

```
Definition list_foo := foo list @app @nth.

Lemma list_foo_lemma : (* Some statement *).
```

Now, because we now that `H_app` and `H_nth` are compatible with their
list counterparts, and because `foo` is polymorphic, the theory of
parametricity says that we can prove

```
Definition H_foo := foo Heap @H_app @H_nth.

Lemma foo_param : forall A (h : Heap A),
                    f (H_foo h) = list_foo (f h).
```

with this lemma in hand, it should be possible to transport properties
of `list_foo` to similar properties of `H_foo`. For instance, as a
trivial example, we can show that `H_app` is associative, up to
conversion to a list:

```
forall A (h1 h2 h3 : Heap A),
  list_foo (H_app h1 (H_app h2 h3)) =
  list_foo (H_app (H_app h1 h2) h3).
```

What's nice about parametricity is that it applies to *any*
parametrically polymorphic function: as long as appropriate
compatibility conditions hold of your types, it should be possible to
relate two instantiations of a given function in a similar fashion to
`foo_param`.

There are two problems, however. The first one is having to change
your base definitions to polymorphic ones, which is probably not so
bad. What's worse, though, is that even though parametricity ensures
that it is always possible to prove lemmas such as `foo_param` under
certain conditions, Coq does not give you that for free, and you still
need to show these lemmas by hand. There are two things that could help
alleviate your pain:

1. There's a [parametricity plugin](https://github.com/mlasson/paramcoq) for Coq (CoqParam) which should
   help deriving the boilerplate proofs for you automatically. I have
   never used it, though, so I can't really say how easy it is to use.
2. The Coq Effective Algebra Library (or [CoqEAL](https://github.com/CoqEAL/CoqEAL), for short) uses
   parametricity to prove things about efficient algorithms while
   reasoning over more convenient ones. In particular, they define
   refinements that allow one to switch between `nat` and `BinNat`, as
   you suggested. Internally, they use an infrastructure based on
   type-class inference, which you could adapt to your original
   example, but I heard that they are currently migrating their
   implementation to use CoqParam instead.

Comment: This way I would still have to rewrite every proof to be parametric, wouldn't I?

Comment: Well, not really. You would have to write some glue proofs to connect the theorems about lists to the ones about heaps, but the proofs on the version on lists would not change.

Comment: But I am using theorems like app_assoc from the standard library. But yeah, I can minimize the efforts, I guess. Thank you!

Comment: I had to do some minor changes to CoqParam to make it compile under Coq 8.4.  https://github.com/larsr/coqparam/commit/d9a39b9479f2ab99dbc34a9622c656f9fed7bcbd

Comment: The author of CoqParam recommended this newer link to the library: https://github.com/mlasson/paramcoq

Comment: @schoppenhauer The point is exactly that you don't need to change the proofs about the list version. Thus, if you are using a lemma like `app_assoc`, you will still be applying the same lemma when proving your algorithm correct. The only things that will change are the definitions of the algorithms themselves, which will become parametric, and the glue lemmas that you'll need to connect the list lemmas to the heap ones. Maybe if you included a concrete usage example I could give you better guidance on how to use this?

Comment: @Arthur Azevedo De Amorim:  I do not have algorithms that I proof correct. I am using non-opaque Lemmas like
`Lemma slice_list_le : forall {A} n (l : list A), n <= ll l -> {l1 : list A & {l2 : list A | l1 ++ l2 = l /\ ll l1 = n}}.` (where `ll` is short for `length`)
from which I extract programs. Maybe this is the misunderstanding?

Comment: @schoppenhauer Oh, I see. If you want to use parametricity in this kind of program, you need to assume more than heap versions of `nth` and `app`: you would probably need to make the definition of `slice_list_le` parametric with respect to an induction principle that behaves like the one for lists, as well as theorems about `nth`, `app`, and this induction principle. On the other hand, it seems a bit strange to extract a heap implementation for `split` based on the one for lists, since it will probably perform poorly: the height of the extracted subheaps will likely be linear...

Comment: @Arthur Azevedo De Amorim: this was just a simple example. Hm. I guess I'll use dependent records which define functions `nth` and `app` as fields, with compatibility-theorems.